# RDKit hook for Pyinstaller to create .exe file

Tags: pyinstaller, hook, rdkit

I'm trying to export a Python file as a `.exe` file with Pyinstaller. My Python program uses the `RDKit` package, which is not supported by Pyinstaller by default. I tried to set the flag `--hidden-import='rdkit'` and I also placed a hook file in the Pyinstaller directory with the code

```
hiddenimports = [
    "rdkit.*",
    "rdkit.ANY.*"
]
```

But I'm still getting a bunch of `'lib not found'` warnings from Pyinstaller. When I run the `.exe` file, I get the error

```
"No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\...\\_MEI84842\\rdkit_pypi.libs\\.load-order-rdkit_pypi-2021.9.2' ".
```

This file is in the `rdkit_pypi.libs` folder, at the same level as the rdkit folder itself.

Does anyone have a proper hook file for RDKit or know how to set the correct path for the said file?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, forcing pyinstaller to add the whole rdkit_pypi.libs folder worked for me. This can be done in two ways :

- **Command Line** : add the --add-data parameter with the location of rdkit_pypi.libs folder

  ```
   pyinstaller --add-data='C:\Python37\Lib\site-packages\rdkit_pypi.libs;rdkit_pypi.libs' "yourprogam.py"
  ```
- **Spec file** : if you are using a spec file to bundle the application, you can set this in the datas section of the Analysis variable

  ```
   a = Analysis(...
        datas=[('C:\\Python37\\Lib\\site-packages\\rdkit_pypi.libs', 'rdkit_pypi.libs')],
        ...
   )
  ```

I actually **didn't** need the `--hidden-import='rdkit'` for it to work.

Hope this will help in your case too.